# Groovy tricky Array List iteration

Tags: java, groovy, iteration, complexity-theory

I'm Iterating over an array list with following output:

0. Richard
1. Collins
2. Ducati
3. 50
4. London
5. Barten

Process finished with exit code 0

All those elements are inside my objet `"Results"`

my code:

```
def list = results[0]
    list.eachWithIndex { val, idx ->
        println "${idx}. ${val}" }
```

With this iteration I'm getting the Index and the element at the same time.

I need to know if it is possible to iterate in the array list and at the same time convert my indexes in words, by example

```
A. Richard
B. Collins
C. Ducati
D. 50
E. London
F. Barten
```

I'm implementing and automation and the system can't catch the Indexes from the elements. Maybe replacing them with words would be possible

Thank you guys!

Comment: This should be doable, what have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to use once you run out of single letters? "Excel-style"?

Comment: @cfrick hello my dear!!! See the resolution below :P 

Ty bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, if you want to cover the case where you run out of one-letter index values:

```
def values   = ['Richard', 'Collins', 'Ducati', '50', 'London', 'Barten']
def alphabet = ('a'..'c')

values.indexed().each { i, v -> 
  def index = encode(i, alphabet)
  println "${index}. $v"
}

String encode(index, alphabet) {  
  def result = new StringBuilder()
  def s = alphabet.size()
  index += s // remove if we are ok with one letter indicies

  while (index >= 0) {
    result.insert(0, alphabet[index % s as int])
    index = (index / s as long) - 1
  }
  
  result
}
```

which, when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
aa. Richard
ab. Collins
ac. Ducati
ba. 50
bb. London
bc. Barten
```

where the alphabet for indicies is configurable via the `('a'..'z')` range syntax.

For a combination of upper case letters and numbers you could for example do:

```
def alphabet = ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')
```

which would produce:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
AA. Richard
AB. Collins
AC. Ducati
AD. 50
AE. London
AF. Barten
```

where the index values would roll over to numbers after the letter `Z`.

With this you would never "run out" of index values even for a large number of input items in the `values` collection. The `encode` method will just produce successively longer index values the larger your input integer value is. To reduce the length of the index values for large input integers you can use a longer alphabet.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. You're a genius!!

Comment: : ) glad it helped. If you feel like this (or any other of the answers) resolves your issue, feel free to mark the relevant answer as accepted. This lets the community know that your question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something similar as

```
branches = ['Richard', 'Collins', 'Ducati', '50', 'London', 'Barten']

char a = 'A'
branches.eachWithIndex { val, idx ->
  println "${(idx + (a as int)) as char}. ${val}" 
}
```

so you can convert the character to an integer (ASCII), then add the value of your index, and then reconvert it to a char. Depending on the number of values in the list you can create a "better" intToString() method, but you should have got the idea in the example

Comment: I think `${(idx + (a as int)) as char}` could be `${(idx + a) as char}`.  I am not sure the `as int` is contributing.

Comment: @Edu Thank you a lot for your time. You're a Star!

Comment: Thank you @jeff Scott Brown